# Show that $\hat{f}^\prime(\omega)=-i\mathscr{F}\{xf(x)f\}$.

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Show that under appropriate conditions $$\hat{f}^\prime(\omega)=-i\mathscr{F}\{xf(x)f\}$$ where $\hat{f}(\omega)$ is defined as the Fourier transform of $f(x)$, or $\mathscr{F}\{f(x)\}$.  So I think that $\hat{f}^\prime(\omega)=\mathscr{F}\{f^\prime(x)\}$.

There's a related problem with $$\hat{f}^{(r)}(\omega)=(-i)^r\mathscr{F}\{x^rf(x)\}.$$

I'm just not sure where to even begin.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\hat{f}' = \mathscr{F}(f')$ is exactly *not* the order you should interpret those operations!

Answer (score 0):

Note the answer depends on how you define the transform.

If $\phi(x) = x f(x)$, then assuming that $\phi$ is integrable, we have
$\hat{\phi} = i \hat{f}'$.

Note that $\hat{f}(t) = \int f(x) e^{-i tx} dx$, then differentiating both
sides with respect to $t$ gives
$\hat{f}'(t) = -i \int f(x) x e^{-i tx} dx$, or
$\hat{\phi} = i \hat{f}'$.